# Can an incorporeal creature turn any object incorporeal with the Ghostly Grasp feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, incorporeal

The Ghostly Grasp feat is described in *Libris Mortis* (page 27) and states:

> You can **wear**, wield, and otherwise use corporeal items as though you were not incorporeal.

Emphasis mine.

According to the incorporeal subtype any “equipment **worn** or carried by an incorporeal creature is also incorporeal”. Once again, emphasis mine. *Libris Mortis* confirms this on page 141 and extends this to the general “objects”:

> An incorporeal creature only shares its incorporeal nature with objects that it actually holds, carries, or wears.

As far as I can find, anything picked up with Ghostly Grasp will instantly become incorporeal together with the creature. This feel unintentional. Or wrong even. Did I miss something? Is Ghostly Grasp documented in any other RAW source, expending on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It's a mess.

By RAW, Ghostly Grasp is completely nonfunctional most of the time. It works for ghosts and other incorporeal edge cases with a Strength score, though, and for them, it doesn't turn objects incorporeal by RAW. See the end for how.

The feat grants this effect:

> **Benefit:** You can wear, wield, and otherwise use corporeal items as though you were not incorporeal.
> **Special:** Without this feat, an incorporeal creature can only wear or wield items that have the ghost touch special ability.

Seems straightforward enough, right? When I first posted an answer to this question, I thought so too, but then I was prompted to do more research, and the whole rules situation around this feat is a *mess.*

The incorporeal subtype was updated in the *Monster Manual III's* glossary (p. 214), to include the following passages, among other things:

> **Any equipment worn or carried by an incorporeal creature is also incorporeal as long as it remains in the creature’s possession.** An object that the creature relinquishes loses its incorporeal quality (and the creature loses the ability to manipulate the object).

So! *Normally,* when an incorporeal creature picks up an object (somehow), it turns incorporeal with them. This is done through *ghost touch* weapons and similar effects in most cases, though there are a few others. Thankfully, these rules are not relevant here, because of Ghostly Grasp's statement that you "use corporeal items as though you were not incorporeal."

This means that when you are choosing to use the feat ("can"), you just ignore *all* of the incorporeal subtype's rules, including the part about turning objects incorporeal. *However...* when using items in this way, you run into some other rules.

**Incorporeal creatures, by and large, have a Strength score of — (a nonability).**

According to the rules for nonabilities, such a creature suffers from the following (*MMIII,* p. 217):

> *Strength:* Any creature that can physically manipulate other objects has at least 1 point of Strength.
>
> A creature with no Strength score can’t exert force, usually because it has no physical body (a prismatic golem, for example). The creature automatically fails Strength checks. If the creature can attack, it applies its Dexterity modifier to its base attack bonus instead of a Strength modifier.

So, while an incorporeal creature with Ghostly Grasp can use objects as if they were not incorporeal, **they cannot exert force, nor can they physically manipulate other objects.** That's a bit of a bummer. They don't even get a place on the [carrying capacity table](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/carryingCapacity.htm).

But hey, thanks to their Ethereal Plane weirdness, ghosts have a Strength score, despite being incorporeal! Or, more particularly, while manifested on the Material Plane, they are incorporeal, and per the incorporeal subtype, have no Strength score (despite having one):

> It [an incorporeal creature] has no Strength score, so its Dexterity modifier applies to both its melee attacks and its ranged attacks.

Luckily, Ghostly Grasp lets our hypothetical ghost use corporeal objects as if they were not incorporeal... which means their Strength score applies, as that rule is no longer in the way.

#### In conclusion

Ghosts and similar beings who have the incorporeal subtype while retaining their Strength score on the stat block can use Ghostly Grasp to pick up corporeal objects. They will *not* turn said objects incorporeal when using them in this way.

Other incorporeal creatures, thanks to their Strength nonability, can take the Ghostly Grasp feat, but cannot exert physical force or lift objects at all. They likewise will not turn objects incorporeal when fruitlessly pushing on an object in this way.

Comment: This question has *really* hurt my brain, and I'm glad someone else was brave enough to take a crack at it. What bothers me about the feat Ghostly Grasp is that you "can… use corporeal items as though you were not incorporeal," which should mean that you *don't* turn corporeal items incorporeal when you grasp them ghostily because that's what happen *normally*, the specifics of the Ghostly Grasp feat overriding the general rules of being incorporeal. But that's such a weird—and grammatically precise—reading that I'm unsure. Can this answer accommodate or refute that reading?

Comment: Actually that's a good point. I'm going to go do more research.

Comment: @HeyICanChan hopefully this helps your hurting brain XD

Comment: Since the Dex score is replacing the Strength for attacks, it might be reasonable to allow it to replace strength to manipulate objects, just to make this feat do its job. alternately, just have a strength score of 10 be assumed for the purposes of this feat, akin to the score of an [*unseen servant*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#unseen-servant). Or get a [hand of the mage](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#hand-of-the-mage "DnDSRD.net's Hand of the Mage entry")...

Comment: @Chemus If you want some stat to replace Str, it most probably should be Cha, certainly not Dex. Dex has nothing to do with exerting force. Cha is questionable, but at least stated by RC to govern interactions between incorporeal creatures, so it may be extended onto this feat. Not if I like this ruling or RC itself.

Comment: Reading “as though you were not incorporeal” as ignoring the incorporeal subtype wholesale is definitely something I did not consider! This instantly makes the entire feat useless because of the lack of Strength, as you say. I do not agree with your assessment of Ghosts though. While a Ghost keeps its Strength score, and applies it on the Ethereal Plane, it does not have a Strength score on the Material Plane. When it becomes a “manifested ghost” through its Manifestation ability, the incorporeal subtype is applied to the manifestation and its Strength score is lost on the Material Plane.

Comment: Marked this as the accepted answer. Even if I do not agree with the reading of Ghosts it does answer my Ghostly Grasp question.

Comment: Isn't a ghost character without telekinesis, mage hand, or something similar "Doing It Wrong"™? (the previous question is intended humorously.) And on a more serious note, would such an ability count as having a strength score for purposes of having/using this feat?

Comment: @Martijn the big thing is that ghosts retain their Str score in the stat blocks; otherwise they would have two scores listed. If something says to do something without the effects of incorporeality, they still *have* that Str score, and now they don't have a line saying they don't have one.

Comment: @nijineko that's a different area of the rules. Telekinesis, Mage Hand, and similar can lift objects but not *wield* them or use them. It's just lifting, and lacks the finesse and opposable-thumbs-ness of Ghostly Grasp unless you have another ability (like through that one feat from.. LoM? Or Master of the Unseen Hand)

Comment: @Forrestfire you are right, I for some reason thought the Manifestation created sort of a second existence with its own stats. Rereading, that is obviously not what it does.

Comment: @Forrestfire Good point. I guess that's one of the few areas where Ghostwalk actually has a useful point or two.

Comment: I'd stick with Cha. Libris Mortis on page 143 explains what happens when an Incorporeal creature loses incorporealness, and while this is not exactly the case, I think it's close enough: "The now-corporeal creature gains a Strength score equal to its Charisma score (not including any nonpermanent modifi ers to Charisma, such as an eagle’s splendor spell)."
I am not entirely sure about interpreting “as though you were not incorporeal” as "incorporeal traits don't apply to you", but in case of doubts I'll rather be over-restrictive than the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, since incorporeal creatures can't generally interact with material objects, the ghostly grasp feat allows an incorporeal creature to pick up / wear the object in the first place, because the creature couldn't do it without the feat (or without the item being Ghost Touch).

The Incorporeal traits do state this: "An object that the creature relinquishes loses its incorporeal quality (**and the creature loses the ability to manipulate the object**)" (emphasis mine), imho this proves that incorporeals don't normally have the ability to pick up corporeal stuff.

The feat's words "You can wear, wield, and otherwise use corporeal items as though you were not incorporeal" don't specify that you count as corporeal *in general*, only for the purpose of touching and picking up stuff.
Once you did pick up the stuff, you "pass" the incorporealness to your equipment, so your carried and worn objects become incorporeal.

In the end, I think that:

- *Ghostly grasp feat* allows you to pick up the object, but that alone could result in an incorporeal carrying around corporeal stuff, and that's lame (can't pass thru solid walls, unsure if strenght or charisma should be applied to swing the weapons...)
- *Incorporeal traits* specify that the items you gasp become incorporeals, thus resolving the aformentioned issues. Also, this is reinforced by the line stating that a weapon wield by an incorporeal creature can't harm a corporeal one, unless it's a magical weapon (a solid weapon would have no reason not to hit a solid target)